# Standard error of the mean of two estimates

Tags: standard-error, meta-analysis

I have been googling for a while to find an answer to this question. I am sure there is plenty of information somewhere but, I don't know why, I really can't find it.

Suppose that you have two estimatesof a certain parameter from two independent studies. For instance, the slope of the regression of y (e.g. body mass of an animal species) on x (e.g. body length). 
You don't know nothing about the sample sizes and you have just the estimates with their standard errors.

How can you calculate the standard errorof the mean of these two estimates? I guess this is something pretty common in meta-analyses but, as my question shows, I am not familiar with these methods.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-variance_weighting

Comment: If you need to do this at all often you might want to invest in learning software to do it. Both Stata and R have extensive facilities for meta-analysis.

Comment: Thanks. I have heard about the inverse variance weighting but did not remember what was for.
Regarding R, that is the language I am used to, I have had a look at {metafor} that is one package for doing meta-analyses.

Comment: If you are planning on possibly doing more than either metafor or meta are well used and further support is available in the r-sig-meta-analysis mailing list https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// for R questions.